# How can I run a shell script every 5 seconds for 2 minutes?

Tags: shell, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have seen many solutions to half my problem - running the script every 5 seconds.

In addition to this I also only want it to run for only 2 minutes.

The point of the script is to sample the RSSI at a certain position for a period of time:

```
#!/bin/bash

RSSI_CSV=$1
DISTANCE=$2
RSSI=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}\')

printf "$DISTANCE,$RSSI\n" >> $RSSI_CSV
```

At the command line it is called with:

```
sh rssi_script.sh output.csv position
```

What would be the most robust solution to solve my problem?

Possibilities I have considered:

- repeat the script 40 times within itself (measure the RSSI 40 times and output it to the CSV 40 times, the position will be the same throughout the experiment) This would also solve the problem of limiting the run to 2 minutes. I might add some new command line arguments which could be difficult to keep track of if I have to change 40 variants every time
- use watch to sample every 5 seconds and cron to limit it to 2 minutes (not 100% cron can do this)
- A while loop for 2 minutes (not sure how to do a while loop like this?) with a 5 second sleep at the end of each loop
- use cron to start the shell script as 40 processes of the script and delay each iteration by 5 seconds, I am not sure how command line arguments would be passed across this and as I said above I might add some new command line arguments so that could cause issues (extra work)

Let me know if there is any info I have missed or would help and thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$3" = "0" ] && { exit; }

RSSI_CSV=$1
DISTANCE=$2
RSSI=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}\')

printf "$DISTANCE,$RSSI\n" >> $RSSI_CSV

sleep 5
N=$3
$0 $1 $2 $((N-1))
```

Run like this:

```
sh rssi_script.sh output.csv position 24
```

Comment: At least use `exec` on the last line as a tail-recursion optimization.

Comment: What do you mean use exec? the new script doesn't seem to work, I get the error rssi_script.sh: 13: rssi_script.sh: rssi_script: not found

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by PeterMmm's input I managed to get it to work, and in fact it works better for me to run N samples with a hard coded rest between them

```
#!/bin/bash

RSSI_CSV=$1
DISTANCE=$2
N=$3

while [ $N -ne 0 ]
do
    RSSI=$(iwconfig wlan0 | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}\')
    printf "$DISTANCE,$RSSI\n" >> $RSSI_CSV
    sleep 2 
    ((N--))
    echo $N
done
exit
```